# Remove a string from all cell of column in a big MySQL table

Tags: mysql

In the IMDB dataset, I want to remove the 'tt' character in the beginning of each title id. I used below query for doing that, but in a big table nothing happend!

```
UPDATE title_akas SET `titleId` = REPLACE(`titleId`, 'tt', '');
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Nothing happened - please elaborate query is fine.(but will remove every occurrence of tt in a string

Comment: Must work. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2460584c67511db9ba6ed83229d213b PS. If `'tt'` may be somewhere except the beginning it will be replaced too.

Comment: @P.Salmon In the title_ratings table (a smaller table) query works fine ... But in the other tables like title_principals (that are big datasets), query executed but all 'tt' still remaining!

Comment: @Akina In the small tables it works fine

Comment: Seems unlikely please add sample data from a large,failing table.

Comment: Table size cannot affect, except execution time.

Comment: Please test UPDATE title_akas SET titleId = REPLACE(titleId, 'tt', '') WHERE (id>=10 AND id <=1000); for checking.

Comment: @jacouh #1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @P.Salmon In this site, https://datasets.imdbws.com/ download title.principals.tsv.gz

Comment: With UPDATE title_akas SET titleId = REPLACE(titleId, 'tt', '') LIMIT 1000;

Comment: @jacouh It works fine for first 1000 rows

Comment: What ide are you using?

Comment: You should first identify id field and update them with limit.

Comment: @P.Salmon XAMPP and phpmyadmin

Comment: @jacouh There is not any faster solution?!

Comment: We cannot do UPDATE title_akas SET titleId = REPLACE(titleId, 'tt', '') LIMIT offset, limit;. As a whole your MySQL memory limit may be a constraint.